# When I use os.system() to open a .py file in Python it automatically closes it immediately. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, os.system

I'm writing a script that needs to open another script, but continue running the main script such that both scripts are running simultaneously.

I've tried `execfile()` but the file doesn't open. When I use `os.system(somefile.py)` it successfully opens the .py file via console but immediately closes it. Are there alternatives so that I can run a python script within a main python script, but have both processes running simultaneously without conflicting one another?

Here is sample code I've tested:

```
import os
file_path = 'C:\\Users\\Tyler\\Documents\\Multitask Bot\\somefile.py'

def main():
    os.system(file_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What does `somefile.py` do then? Should it keep running for more than an instant?

Answer (score 3):

`execfile()` and `os.system()` will block the parent process until the child exits. Use `subprocess.Popen()`, e.g.

```
import subprocess, time
file_path = 'C:\\Users\\Tyler\\Documents\\Multitask Bot\\somefile.py'

def main():
    child = subprocess.Popen(['python', file_path])
    while child.poll() is None:
        print "parent: child (pid = %d) is still running" % child.pid
        # do parent stuff
        time.sleep(1)
    print "parent: child has terminated, returncode = %d" % child.returncode

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is just one way to handle it. You may want to collect stdout and/or stderr from the child and possibly send data to the child's stdin. Read up on the subprocess module.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run another script simultaneously, consider the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: I agree with @Neil... os.system() will wait until, the command finishes, IIRC.  If you really want it to run in parallel, the subprocess module is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be that that file is not executed in `C:\\Users\\Tyler\\Documents\\Multitask Bot\\`
but somewhere else. The local import may fail.

could you try executing `os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Tyler\\Documents\\Multitask Bot\\')` before `os.system` ?